# How can I use token fields with acts_as_taggable_on and formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token, formtastic, acts-as-taggable-on

I would like to be able to use the token fields (found here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) with formtastic to allow users to input tags (I am using acts_as_taggable_on).

Can someone walk me through an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the time for a full walk-through, but the guts of this seems to be that a `text_field` has a `data-pre` attribute with some JSON in it. The way to add attributes to inputs in Formtastic is via the :input_html option, so this:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :author_tokens, "Authors" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :author_tokens, "data-pre" => @book.authors.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
</p>
```

Might be translated to something like:

```
<%= f.input :author_tokens, :input_html => { "data-pre" => @book.authors.map(&:attributes).to_json } %>
```

The rest is gluing CSS to HTML and finding the right DOM element to apply the jQuery to (view source is your friend).